# Short phrase to indicate two tables are placed next to each other?

Tags: phrase-request, vocabulary

Found this [post](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Never-Mix-Sushi-with-DML.aspx) making a joke on the use of `JOIN` in a Japanese restaurant. This instruction intends to tell customers not to rearrange tables, by placing them next to each other, thus making a "bigger table".

[image: Instruction]

What is the correct word or phrase to be used here in place of `JOIN`, such as:

> Please do not **WORD or PHRASE here** tables in this area.

I know that the message can be conveyed by rearrangement of words, but curious to know if there's a word or phrase that can retain the same word order.

Comment: The joke is more to do with the capitalization of the sentence than with the meaning of the sentence *per se* - "Join" is a valid (although slightly stilted) word to use here, but it should not be all capitalized. A fully capitalized "JOIN" in the middle of a sentence looks like the database programming language SQL, which is why the author of the joke thinks it is funny.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most people would not have a problem understanding this wording, though it is definitely not something a native speaker would say. It is amusing because [`JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) is a command used to combine database tables. Only people familiar with databases would have any reason to laugh at this.

I think the best substitute would be pretty much what you already said:

> Please do not **rearrange the** tables in this area.

This foils the joke, and sounds more natural to a native speaker. If you want to specifically address making "bigger" tables, you can say:

> Please do not **push together any** tables in this area.

**push together** sounds a little more natural, and adding "any" makes it flow a little better.

Comment: Is this my following sentence still grammatical? "Please do not put the tables back to back in this area".

Comment: Yeah, the SQL JOIN command is indeed the joke. Writing only that word in all caps also helped. :)

Comment: @jeysmith It is definitely grammatically correct, and people would know what you meant. But it is a little confusing to say "back-to-back" since tables are usually symmetrical, and don't really have "backs" or "fronts".

Comment: Thanks Gray, and by the way a 'TABLE' can also be CREATE, TRUNCATE, ALTER and DROP :-))

Comment: I'm a native speaker, and the first word I thought of was "join". Also, "join" would be a subset of "rearrange", as "join" would mean "move tables so as to put two tables end to end, or combine two tables into one," while "rearrange" would cover a much broader set of actions, such as turning a rectangular table 90°.

Comment: @J.R. Yes. I am as well. I did consider that 'rearrange' was a change in meaning, but it also makes for a better rule (in my opinion, of course). Rearranging does include "joining" them, but it also includes shifting things around in general. To me, join sounds a bit unnatural, but I definitely understood the intended meaning. If I were to ask you to help me "join" two tables, I would say "Can you help me push/put these together?" rather than "join" them. I can't put my finger on why it sounds off. It is common to "rearrange" furniture, but "joining" it is not something I think I've heard.

Comment: @J.R. *Join* seems okay to me, too.  (Just my opinion!)

Comment: @Gray - "push together" - that's a great answer! _Please do not push together tables in this area_ (or maybe, _Please do not push tables together in this area_). It is clear and sounds somewhat natural, too. I think you should edit your answer and add that in.

Comment: @J.R. Ok, that is a good point. I was trying to hard to think of a synonym instead of just saying what came to me.

Comment: @Gray: I've fallen into that trap more than once, getting so caught up in trying to find a synonym that the most natural way to say something doesn't occur to me until an hour or two later. I'm glad these sites let us edit our own posts!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as a database guy, I see this as an old joke. But to a normal human being, I think this would be a perfectly natural sentence.

There is a potential ambiguity: Do you mean, "Do not move or re-arrange tables", or do you mean, "Do not sit at a table where others are already seated"? I'd be tempted to think the second. If there is a group of people already sitting at a table, and you wish to also sit at that table -- whether because you know them or because there's no room anywhere else or whatever -- the common phrasing is, "May I join you?"

Comment: I would think owners (presumably, the people who put up the sign) would be more likely to object to tables being moved than to people filling empty seats. In fact, I think they'd encourage filling empty seats if they could get away with it. Two people sitting at a table with four seats usually means that two other guests may have to wait for someone to finish before taking their seats.

Comment: @Gray Hmm, probably so. I could see the owners posting such a sign if there had been a problem with people walking in and sitting down at a table with other people. Like, I don't know, if it's a restaurant frequented by celebrities and fans have been coming in and trying to join their party or some such. But yeah, your theory is more likely.

Comment: So you're saying there's only 10 kinds of people in this world, those who know SQL and those who don't? ;-)

Comment: There are 3 kinds of people in the world: those who can count, and those who can't. :-)